# HTML dropdown can't capture onChange() if there is only one value in dropdown using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using Java Script , for selecting value of drop-down.
I need do do some action on OnChange event, But if there is only one option in drop-down I am not able to capture it in onChange event.
My drop-down is formed dynamically , so don't know how many options I'll get how many options , but I am facing problem if there is just one option.
Is there any way to capture OnChange event for with only one ?

Comment: use "onClick" beside onChange

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, can you please add some code sample of what you have tried? Take a quick look at our guide http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how you can ask questions which will help others give good answers.

Comment: if there is one value in dropdown ,how can i change onChange from onClick in dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know  how many options you get, add a default option with value = ""

```
<select onChange="alert('hello')">
<option value="" >Select an option</option>
<option value="option1">Option 1</option>
</select>
```

Edit :

```
    <select onmousedown="this.value='';">
    var vehicleOption="";
    for (var vehicleOptionIterator = 0; vehicleOptionIterator < splitVechilePlateNo.length; vehicleOptionIterator++) 
    {
            vehicleOption += "<option value=" + splitVechilePlateNo[vehicleOptionIterator].split('-')[0] + ">" + splitVechil‌​ ePlateNo[vehicleOptionIterator].split('-')[1] + "</option>";
    }
```

Comment: i dont have option tag in html. i just generated dynamically .

Comment: for(var vehicleOptionIterator=0; vehicleOptionIterator < splitVechilePlateNo.length; vehicleOptionIterator++){
             if(vehicleOptionIterator == 0){
                  vehicleOption = "<option value="+splitVechilePlateNo[vehicleOptionIterator].split('-')[0]+">"+splitVechilePlateNo[vehicleOptionIterator].split('-')[1]+"</option>";
              }
              else{
                  vehicleOption += "<option value="+splitVechilePlateNo[vehicleOptionIterator].split('-')[0]+">"+splitVechilePlateNo[vehicleOptionIterator].split('-')[1]+"</option>";
              }

Comment: i dont want select an option comment. bcoz my first vechile plate no should be in first drop down value.is any other solution?

Comment: Check my answer,  add onmousedown() listener to SELECT tag

Comment: bro its working fine.but whats the problem is its take time and i have to choose two times. is any there solution?

Comment: its based on d vehicle,if 10 vehicles in my dropdown means its working fine in onchange(), but what d problem is ,if it is one vehicle means onchange() is not working

Comment: if number of vehicle is 1 then add 1 dummy option. Then it will work